# Tiling a 5-by-5 bathroom with L-shaped triomino tiles

Tags: tiling, polyomino

The following puzzle appeared in the Cambridge, UK February 2024 MathsJam Shout:

**Tiling with Triominoes**

Imagine tiling a 5-by-5 bathroom with L-shaped triomino tiles.

[image: 5 x 5 grid AND L-shaped triomino]

Clearly, not every square can be covered, since 3 doesn't divide exactly into 25. Can you find a way to cover 24 of the 25 squares? What are the possible positions for the un-tiled square?

Clarification:  The triomino tiles can be rotated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/can-you-put-l-trominos-to-fill-the-figure Even though it isn't an exact duplicate, the answer is practically the same.

Comment: @mathlander I agree that https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/can-you-put-l-trominos-to-fill-the-figure is a very similar question but the answers to that question only partially answer this question.  For example, those other answers don’t show if a corner square in this question can be the un-tiled square.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The missing square has to be one of these:

> [image]
> Since each triomino can only cover one of them, we can only cover 8 of the 9 with our 8 triominos.

Demonstration that any of these is possible:

> [image]
> and rotations

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way

> ```
> A A H H G
> A B H G G
> B B . F F
> C D D F E
> C C D E E
> ```

> Which is made up of four 3x2 sets.

Answer (score 2):

There are

> 128

solutions. Of course, most of those solutions are related to each other via rotation and reflection.

Here are all the solutions, found using Knuth's [Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X). The solutions are displayed as an animated SVG image.

> [image: 5x5 Tromino tilings, SVG]

Here are the solutions in a GIF anim.

> [image: 5x5 Tromino tilings, GIF]